# Making a variable bold when put in p.text function

Tags: javascript, data-visualization

So i have this p.text function that shows me The text, The name of a country (d.properties.name) and The value this country hold (d.properties.value)
How do i for instance make the country name appear in bold?

```
var countryHeight = d.properties.value;
var countryName = d.properties.name;
    p.text(function(countryHeight){return "The Average Height of Men in " +  d.properties.name + " = " + d.properties.value})
    .style("color", "red")
    .style("font-size", "150%")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are injecting this into an HTML page (webpage), then you can include markup inside the text function.

```
var countryHeight = d.properties.value;
var countryName = d.properties.name;
p.text(function(countryHeight){return "The Average Height of Men in <b>" +  d.properties.name + "</b> = " + d.properties.value})
    .style("color", "red")
    .style("font-size", "150%");
```